# WSO2 EI Handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to write an Handler for the EI server and I need in this handler to access to some transport information like:

- The http return code
- The HTTP first line of request from the client
  Pratically, I need the same information provided for the access log but I need it in the handler

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the medium article written in [1] which is used to develop a log handler. Based on the requirement the handler can be modified

[1]-https://medium.com/@snsavithrik1/custom-wso2-synapse-handler-to-log-api-related-transactions-7c2e314313c6